# Error 500 with CURL - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have written a PHP script that auhtenticates me and send back an URL with a ticket : www.example.com/login?ticket=xxxx

When I enter this URL in the navigator, I does work perfectly. When doing this, checking the sent HTTP Header confirms that no POST variables are required, no cookie is sent.

When sending exactly the same HTTP header through CURL, I keep getting a 500 error with this description :

> --cas:authenticationFailure code='INVALID_TICKET'--

However the ticket itself cant be invalid while it perfectly works in a navigator.

The configuration of CURL is the following :

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 0);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11');
```

Thanks in advance for helping on this.

Comment: Not sure on this topic but are the tickets IP specific? If the scripts are running on the server and your browser isn't, might that invalidate the ticket for the PHP CURL script?

Comment: Can you try comparing the request made by the navigator, and the request made by CURL, with a proxy recording tool like Fiddler?  That would determine pretty quickly what the differences are. In theory, if two web requests are byte-by-byte 100% identical, the remote server cannot tell the difference, so there must be *something* different about the two requests, like a header, cookie, etc.

Comment: Are you sure no cookies recorded earlier are sent and make the request work?

Comment: THere are no cookie sent for sure. IP is a good idea but probably not the issue here because the script is run locally (wamp). The full header is : GET /Login?ticket=xxx HTTP/1.1
Host: ent.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: An additionnal experience : If I use the ticket once in the navigator, closes it, reopen it and send again the URL, I get the same error than in CURL. So it seems like using CURL makes the ticket expire. Any idea of how does that happens ?

Comment: If you ignore the CURL script and try load page in the browser, close the browser and then open it again and reload page, does the ticket still work?

Comment: No it doesnt work twice.

Comment: Do the tickets only work once? If you get a new ticket and try load PHP CURL script directly before trying it in the browser, does it work then? Another thing to look at is to ensure the HTTP/HTTPS part of the URL is correct in the CURL script. Browsers auto-affix this when it is missing whereas CURL does not.

Comment: To be more precise : I can generate a ticket in a dedicated CURL script. If I use this ticket in a navigator it does work. If I use it in a simple CURL script (above), it fails.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure how you were generating the tickets. I'm out of ideas then if the URL is fully formed with HTTP/HTTPS and www in the CURL script. Probably not the issue though with a 500 error.